# Why doesn't this code display what I think it should?

Tags: c++

I'm stuck and everything is correct except the Grade wont display, any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void calcScore(int grade, double&total);

int main()
{   
    //declare variables
    int score       = 0;
    int totalPoints = 0;  //accumulator
    char grade      = ' ';

    //get first score
    cout << "First score (-1 to stop): ";
    cin >> score;

    while (score != -1)
    {
        //update accumulator, then get another score
        totalPoints += score;
            cout << "Next score (-1 to stop): ";
            cin >> score;
    }   //end while


    //display the total points and grade
    cout << "Total points earned: " << totalPoints << endl;
    cout << "Grade: " << grade << endl;
    return 0;
}   //end of main function


void calcScore(int grade, double & total)
{
    if (total >= 315)
            grade = 'A';
    else if (total >= 280)
            grade = 'B';
    else if (total >= 245)
            grade = 'C';
    else if (total >= 210)
            grade = 'D';
    else
            grade = 'F';
}
```

Comment: It does not appear you are changing the value of `grade` from its initialized value of `' '`.

Answer (score 6):

You've tagged this as homework, so I won't show you a code solution. A couple of things for you to look at:

1. Your `calcScore` function is never being called anywhere.
2. You're passing `grade` to `calcScore` by value, so you'll be operating upon a local copy of `grade` within your `calcScore` function. **[Is that really what you want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)**
3. You've declared `grade` as `char` in main, but as an `int` in the `calcScore` declaration. Do you understand the relationship between the two?

Good luck! :)

Comment: @Ryan In answer to your comment "So what if I did this?": it would behave differently. :) In seriousness, if you don't call calcScore from your main(), it will never be executed. As to the other two points, ask yourself how you will return the `grade` from calcScore.

Comment: @Ryan As a further hint, it might help you to spot what's currently going on if you initialise `grade` to something other than a space - for example, to a 'Z'.